# What does the phrase 「あんのかないのんか」 mean?

Tags: dialects, phrases

> A: その　たったひとつの自由すらうばわれてしまったら　おれには　なにが　のこるっていうんだい。
>
> B: どうしたい　ジョー　やる気が**あんのかないのんか**！

It is said by Kansai-speaking comic character. I'm not sure if it would mean something like 'do it or not.'

Is 「あんのか」 contracted from 「あるのか」?

Comment: ないのんか, is that a typo?

Comment: No, I have checked the manga again. It is actually written as I have originally posted. I am also curious why there is 「ん」in that position.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. Unless the character speaks some rare non-stereotypical dialect, I think it's likely to be a typo by the author. By I'm also confused by your statement that the character speaks Kansai, since あんのか doesn't seem very Kansai to me, rather Eastern/Standard. Kansai would be more like あるんかないんか.

Answer (score 5):

In standard Japanese, it would be the same as saying 「あるのかないのか」. The phrase in question basically means "do you intend to do it or not?"